# /etc/shadow on Mac

Tags: linux, osx, bash

I've been trying to run this Linux passwd-generator file on my Mac. I modified enough the script to make it to work well with directories under OSX:

```
#!/bin/sh
# build-passwd.sh - creates a password file which contains all OS users (except root)
PASSWDIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)/etc
PASSWFN=$PASSWDIR/passwd
if [ ! -d "$PASSWDIR" ]; then
mkdir $PASSWDIR
echo "$PASSWDIR created"
fi
sudo awk -F":" '
BEGIN {OFS=":"}
{if ($1 != "root" && $2 != "!" && $2 != "*") print $1,$2}
' /etc/shadow > $PASSWFN **<===here's my problem**
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
echo "Password file saved to $PASSWFN"
fi
```

But didn't succeed because there is no "/etc/shadow" on Mac.

So do you know if there is some alternative to this? (I also tried to copy/paste the file from my Linux installation using the same password)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with Lion, there is a shadow file per user. All of those are stored in `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users` directory and are accessible by root only. For example:

```
$ ls -lah /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/
total 296
drwx------  77 root  wheel   2.6K Jul 27 20:30 .
drw-------  12 root  wheel   408B Jul 27 20:30 ..
-rw-------   1 root  wheel   4.0K Jul 27 20:30 Guest.plist
-rw-------   1 root  wheel   260B Jul 27 20:17 _amavisd.plist
-rw-------   1 root  wheel   254B Jul 27 20:17 _appleevents.plist
-rw-------   1 root  wheel   261B Jul 27 20:17 _appowner.plist
-rw-------   1 root  wheel   276B Jul 27 20:17 _appserver.plist
```

Also, those are binary property list files. The easiest way of viewing them is using `plist` command. For example:

```
$ plutil -p /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/root.plist 
{
  "smb_sid" => [
    0 => "XXXX-XXXX"
  ]
  "uid" => [
    0 => "0"
  ]
  "passwd" => [
    0 => "XXYYXX"
  ]
}
```

Comment: For more, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/ .

Comment: I am not sure this this has changed since Lion but I just tried to access this `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/...` and only got up to `/nodes/` before I couldn't go any further. Also, after `cd`ing into it and trying to do a `ls -l` I was returned `Operation not permitted`. Any reason as to why?

Answer (score 7):

Mac OS X doesn't use the standard /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow. Instead, it uses a database. There use to be a GUI called NetInfo, but that has been replaced with the `dscl` command (Directory Services Command Line).

```
$ dscl
> read /Local/Default/Users/David Password
Password: ********
```

Unfortunately, that's about as far as I can get with the utility. It printed out asterisks instead of the password. Maybe there's a way to make it give up the hash, but I haven't found it.

Her's an article detailing using [DSCL and cracking passwords](http://www.defenceindepth.net/2009/12/cracking-os-x-passwords.html) on a Mac.