# BASH: Check in /etc/shadow if user password is locked

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression, users

**Objective:** Check in `/etc/shadow` if user password is locked, i.e. if the first character in the 2nd field in /etc/shadow, which contains the user's hashed password, is an exclamation mark ('!')

**Desired output:** a variable named `$disabled` containing either 'True' or 'False'

Username is in the `$uname` varable and I do something like this:

```
disabled=`cat /etc/shadow |grep $uname |awk -F\: '{print$2}'`
# I now have the password and need one more pipe into the check for the character
# which is where I'm stuck. I would like to do like (in PHP syntax):
| VARIABLE=="!"?"True":"False"`
```

This is a fragment of a script that will be run by Cron with root permissions, so there is access to all desirable information.

Comment: Bear in mind that not all operating systems have a "shadow" file, and those that do differ in the flag conventions for "locked" accounts. This question is actually specific, per the reference to `!`, to the shadow password mechanism in Linux operating systems.

Comment: Excellent remark - and you're absolutely right. Fortunately, my script is intended for an environment, in which only a select few Linux distros are in play. I should be good ;)

Comment: Only until those distributions adopt replacement systems such as [tcb from OpenWall](https://openwall.com/tcb/) or an implementation of [Daniel Rench's userdir](https://web.archive.org/web/20030919191907/http://dren.ch:80/userdir/), or someone decides to employ LDAP.  (-:

Comment: We're in exotic territory here :) but Mandriva and Gentoo are not in play, nor is any BSD at this time :)
LDAP...true: this script is no good there but there are tools in abundance available to audit users in LDAP, so I'm not too worried ;)

Comment: Don't be so sure.  This is an idea that has been independently invented three times at least, in this century alone.  And that's not counting MacOS.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44517/

Comment: Useless use of `cat`; `grep` can take a file as a command line argument.

Comment: Useless use of `grep` too; `awk` is perfectly capable of finding a string in a file.

Comment: Nitpick: `/etc/shadow` does not store passwords, so you can not check if the first character of the password here is `!`, because it stores cryptographically irreversible data derived from the password through functions such as `bcrypt`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm guessing DavDav meant to ask if the first character of the field that normally stores the password hash (not the password itself) is a `!`. So, you're technically right, but that seems like a typo in the question rather than a flaw in the underlying intent.

Comment: @DavidZ Like a wrote, a nitpick, because everyone understood the meaning of the phrase, but for future reference it is wrong to get the idea that passwords are stored there, hence my slight correction.

Comment: @mustaccio Please elaborate on the awk way! I've already achieved my goal with this script but I'm in a constant learning process, so...teach me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do it all with awk?

```
awk -F: '/<username>/ {if(substr($2,1,1) == "!"){print "True"} else {print "False"}}' /etc/shadow
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was after. My script is now completed - thanks.

Comment: Well, this needs to create a sub process. My proposal works in the shell and does not need a sub-process.

Comment: @schily no need for a script wrapper round awk, if you really wanted you could make it an alias...

Comment: `/<username>/` matches on whole records that match the `<username>` extended regexp. So for instance, `j.doe` would match on a record that has `b.judoer` in the user field or `j7doe` in the password hash field.

Comment: It's just a placeholder to show sheet to put the username

Answer (score 26):

### Don't parse the `shadow` file manually

Parsing such files is fragile if you fail to account for all eventualities (for example, disabled passwords are often encoded as a single `*`; do other solutions deal with that?).

Additionally, authentication may not happen through `shadow` (but instead through NIS or ldap or who knows what).There are standard tools that will deal with all this for you. In this case, `passwd`:

> **-S, --status**
>   Display account status information. The status information consists of 7 fields. The first
>   field is the user's login name. The second field indicates if the user account has a locked
>   password (L), has no password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field gives the
>   date of the last password change. The next four fields are the minimum age, maximum age,
>   warning period, and inactivity period for the password. These ages are expressed in days.

So `passwd -S | cut -d ' ' -f 2` will yield what you need. A simple if/then will translate it to your desired variable:

```
if [ "$(passwd -S "$USER" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)" = "P" ]
then
    disabled="False"
else
    disabled="True"
fi
```

The same applies to locking a user's password; this is preferably done through `usermod` (`--lock` option), not editing `shadow` manually.

Comment: Also, you need root permissions to read the `shadow` file (the permissions requirement is the main reason the file exists after all).

Comment: @SimonRichter As far as I can gather, you need root to run `passwd -S` for other users, too. Not for your own user, though.

Comment: FWIW, it (incorrectly) reports `L` for my own (Kerberos with LDAP) account here, I suppose because it can't get hold of the password hash. Chances are `passwd -S` is not going to be useful for many authentication schemes beyond /etc/shadow anyway.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hmm, that's a shame... I'd rather hoped they would map some LDAP attribute to that field. (I haven't used LDAP in a while, so I couldn't check that it actually did)

Comment: `getent passwd $ACCOUNT` gets the entry from whatever source behind is used for authentication.

Comment: Wait a minute; there's supposed to be two possible encodings; one for locked and one for not locked but no possible password.

Answer (score 3):

```
U=$user LC_ALL=C awk -F: < /etc/shadow '
  $1 "" == ENVIRON["U"] {
    user_found = 1
    if ($2 ~ /^!/) {
      print "True"
      exit 0
    } else {
      print "False"
      exit 1
    }
  }
  END {
    if (!user_found) {
      print "False"
      print "User "ENVIRON["U"]" not found" > "/dev/stderr"
      exit 2
    }
  }'
```

`$1 "" == ENVIRON["U"]` compares the first field with `ENVIRON["U"]` lexically. Without the `""`, the fields could end-up being compared numerically if they look like numbers (causing `inf` to match against `INF` or `Infinity` for instance).

Without `LC_ALL=C`, since some `awk` implementations use  `strcoll()` for the `==` lexical comparison, it could end-up checking wrong entries for user names that sort the same.

Answer (score -1):

A user is locked when the passwd field is the string `*LK*`, but you cannot check this as `/etc/shadow` is only readable by root for security reasons.

If permissions are not an issue, try this:

```
while IFS=: read USER PW REST; do 
    if [ "$USER" = "$uname" ]; then 
            if [ "$PW" = "*LK*" ]; then 
                    echo "$uname" Locked 
            fi 
    fi 
done < /etc/shadow
```

Edit: Moved IFS=: to make the code simpler

Comment: I have edited my question - permissions is not an issue. Last time I checked, an exclamation mark in first position in the password means that the password is locked.

Comment: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man4/shadow.4.html Anything that cannot be an encrypted passwd makes the account unusable, but if you use the incorrect pattern, this may be missinterpreted and please note: this file is shared between different platforms via e.g. `NIS`.

Comment: `*LK*` is only for SysV systems, `passwd -l` (for locking) on Linux-based does use `!`. `passwd -l` doesn't make the account unusable, it only disables password authentication.

Comment: Indeed, the question's objective says "is the first character in user's password an exclamation mark ('!')"

Comment: Using `IFS=: read -r user pw rest` avoids having to save and restore `$IFS`. See also `-r` to avoid the backslash processing (backslash not expected in /etc/shadow though)

Comment: Important: This will not work with a historic Bourne Shell, since it eats multiple field separators instead of creating empty fields.